# Can I read the name of a type or property from a list in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using a query

```
FOREACH(item IN $list | CREATE (p:Person) SET p.name = item.indexPropertyValue)
```

where `$list` is a list of maps. What I really want to do is something like

```
FOREACH(item IN $list | CREATE (p:item.typeName) SET p.item.indexProperty = item.indexPropertyValue)
```

which is syntactically wrong. Is there a way to read the type name and property name from a list, or are they required to be "constants"?

Comment: Are you trying to create node labels dynamically, right?

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean, but I guess so. I want to label a node with the value of a string that I get as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve your requirement purely with Cypher. But you can install [APOC procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) and use the procedure `apoc.create.node`. This procedure creates nodes with dynamic labels and the specified properties.

The procedure signature is:

```
CALL apoc.create.node(['Label'], {key:value,…​})
```

Your code will looks like:

```
FOREACH(item IN $list |
    CALL apoc.create.node([item.typeName], {item : { indexProperty : item.indexPropertyValue} })
)
```